# Formatting species names in a column in R

Tags: string, r, title-case

I am working with quite a large database containing a column called '`Species_name`' this is a factor column and includes the names of around 40 different species. As R is often case sensitive (***particularly when plotting graphs***) I was wondering if it was possible to write a line of code which formats all the species names in this column to Capital then lower case i.e. Brown crab, Blonde ray etc.

Apologies for my ignorance - I am new to R!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to define a function that transforms `character` values to the case you want. R has built in `tolower` and `toupper` but nothing that capitalizes them the way you want.

```
capitalize <- function(x){
  first <- toupper(substr(x, start=1, stop=1)) ## capitalize first letter
  rest <- tolower(substr(x, start=2, stop=nchar(x)))   ## everything else lowercase
  paste0(first, rest)
}
```

Then you only apply the function to the levels of your factor variable. That's one advantage of factors:

```
levels(data$Species_name) <- capitalize(levels(data$Species_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use functions from stringi package:

```
require(stringi)
x <- "alA Ma KOTA 123"
stri_join(stri_trans_toupper(stri_sub(x,1,1)),stri_trans_tolower(stri_sub(x,2)))
## [1] "Ala ma kota 123"
```

I think is worth mentioning that there is function which transform string to Title Case, but not in way that you are looking for.

```
stri_trans_totitle(x)
## [1] "Ala Ma Kota 123"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
levels(df$Species_name) <- gsub("^([a-z])", "\\U\\1", tolower(levels(df$Species_name)), perl = TRUE)
```

Explanaiton:

First, make all names lower case using `tolower`, then capitalize first letter using `gsub`.

`^([a-z])` goes after the first letter, while `\\U\\1` means to capitalize it in `Perl`, thus the `perl = TRUE`